# How to check Java String second digit is in range 1 through 5 inclusive

Tags: java, string

I want to check a Java String second digit is in range 1 ~ 5 (inclusive)
e.g. String s = "151309";
Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm a python programmer, in python we use :
if s[1] in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']: return True

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
char c = s.charAt(1);
if (c >= '1' && c <= '5') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use charAt() on your string, to figure out if the number is in a given range.

Example:

```
char secondNumber = s.charAt(1);
if (secondNumber >= 1 && secondNumber <= 5) {
     //do something...
}
```

Comment: This should be ``secondNumber >= '1' && secondNumber <= '5'`` because you're looking for the character value rather than the actual integer value.